# Custom environment template for a TFS release

Tags: tfs, tfs-2018

How do I create a custom environment template for a TFS release?
Here is the document to delete it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/env-templates?view=vsts#how-do-i-delete-a-custom-environment-template

I am trying to add a new custom template to the TFS 2018 release section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's under the ellipsis when you click on an environment in the pipeline view, next to "Delete" and "Move".

[image: Save as template]

Comment: Thanks! One follow up question. Is there any way to transfer the saved template to another instance of TFS? I have the json file created by the template.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I find task groups to be a lot more useful and flexible than environment templates.